# Tracking CPU and memory usage with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, memory-management, cpu-usage

I'm looking for a good way to track CPU and memory usage for a variety of web applications and to be able to cross-reference this information with information on Google Analytics.  For example, I'd like to be able to generate a report that shows the CPU and memory usage along with number of hits averaged over minute periods.  One way I thought this could be solved is by adding custom page-level variables to Google Analytics for tracking CPU and memory usage.  My questions:

1. For those familiar with GA reporting as it pertains to custom variables, is this possible?
2. Is there a better way to generate the kind of report I'm seeking?  Perhaps even without using GA?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Google analytics API to push this data directly from the web page via javascript, or from the server using whatever language is relevant.

I've seen at least one large implementation use the API for UX A/B testing by way of event tracking, but there's no reason you couldn't store whatever related data you'd like.